# Jeditable not working with Jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jeditable, autogrow

I was using Jeditable(with type autogrow) for editing text within a div which has similar siblings. Then I used Sortable for all the siblings and then jeditable wont cancel edit when click outside.

Really in a pickle as I need sortable functionality and dont want to lose the editing.

Edit:
Also, once I click to edit a text, It will not allow me to select any text from the textarea. This is getting real worse. Sortable seems like too much for my bloated app

Comment: I've found that the jEditable plugin doesn't seem to work properly in list item's I created a test case <div><ul><li><span class="editable">Edit Me</span></li></ul></div> and it loads correctly but you are unable to select any text etc

seems to be a bug I'll update if I find a fix

Answer (score 0):

I hate bringing back an old thread, but this was one of the top results in Google and it had no solution.

Since I can't see the code, this is only a guess, but I had the same problem and this solved it.

.disableSelection() affects all children of the sortable, and you only want it to affect the direct children, just like sortable does.  Just change it to .children().disableSelection(); and it should be fine.  :)

Example:

```
$(".example").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sample"
}).children().disableSelection();
```

Edit:  I tried this out on a new project, and it didn't work the way it did on another.  But, removing disableSelection() all together works, and I didn't find that it messed anything up.